# How can I add a Website Project in a solution but it should be excluded from source control?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops, vs-web-site-project

I currently have a solution with a couple of Class Library Projects and Web Application Projects and all of these are bound to a source control (VS Team Services). Now I added an Existing Website Project in the same solution by choosing a Local IIS instance. However, I don't want this Website Project to be in source control.

I have tried File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control ... and then clicked on the website project and then clicked Unbind. By doing this, it seems that the project was unbound. However, as soon as I close the solution it asks me to save the .sln file and seems that it restored the Scc*** info in the file.

I also tried editing the .sln file and set the SccProjectEnlistmentChoice* = 0 (of the website project, under GlobalSection) and then set the ProjectSection of the WebsiteProject to

```
SccProjectName = ""
SccAuxPath = ""
SccLocalPath = ""
SccProvider = ""
```

instead of "SAK". This actually worked for me but everytime I open the solution, Visual Studio alerts an error saying "Unspecified error". This is the closest I got into solving this.

Is there a proper way of doing this? I think the proper way should be the "Unbind" method but it seems that it's not working as expected.

I also would like to avoid using .tfignore if possible.

Let me know of other solutions.

I also asked this question at [MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c5d70700-1bca-4fb4-bb43-1e8b00bdea92/how-can-i-add-a-website-project-in-a-solution-that-should-be-excluded-from-source-control?forum=visualstudiogeneral) but I think there are more people that may respond here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web sites have not been an official thing to do for over 5 years and 3 versions of the product. Thus the support is a little spotty in places.

Because a Web Site does not have a Project file it inherits its source bindings from the Solution. This is as far as the legacy support goes.

I would recommend that you upgrade your Web Site to a Web Application. You can then set binding explicitly for it in the project file.